# Why cant I use use an attribute as a resource name in a chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have this attribute defined in my default attributes file:

```
default['remote_machine']['user']['file_name'] = '/folder/path/file_name.html'
```

And I am trying to reference this attribute name in a recipe as follows:

```
list_of_nodes = search(:node,"name:production_* AND name:*app*")

template default['remote_machine']['user']['home']['file_name'] do #ERROR HERE
  source "file_name.html.erb"
  mode "755"
  variables(
    :list_of_ips=>list_of_nodes
  )
```

Trying to upload this cookbook, I get an error as:

```
FATAL: ArgumentError: You must supply a name when declaring a default resource
```

If I provide a string containing the path as the argument to the resource, it works.

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi theTuxRacer. If any of the answers solved your problem, could you please mark one as correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two issues here, the first is more obvious that the second

### setting vs accessing

When you set a node attribute, you specify the precedence level (like automatic, default, normal, and override). Typically this is done in your attribtue files.

When you access that information, it's stored on the `node` object, so you need to use the `node` key:

```
node['remote_machine']['user']['home']['file_name']
```

### wrong attribute

But the real reason you're getting this error is that you are accessing an undefined attribute. You've defined `remote_machine.user.file_name` but you're using `remote_machine.user.home.file_name`

Answer (score 4):

You set attributes based on the precedence level (default, normal, override), but you access them through the `node` object:

```
template node['remote_machine']['user']['home']['file_name'] do
```